# How do I make a time delay?

Tags: python, delay, sleep, timedelay

How do I put a time delay in a Python script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How do I get my Python program to sleep for 50 milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377454/how-do-i-get-my-python-program-to-sleep-for-50-milliseconds)*

Comment: Voting to reopen because this seems to be a better canonical than the linked dupe.

Answer (score 3468):

This delays for 2.5 seconds:

```
import time

time.sleep(2.5)
```

---

Here is another example where something is run approximately once a minute:

```
import time

while True:
    print("This prints once a minute.")
    time.sleep(60) # Delay for 1 minute (60 seconds).
```

Comment: if you need some conditions to happen. It better to user threading.Event.wait.

Comment: Well... it'll print less frequently than that, because it takes time to print and handle all the buffers that entails (possibly doing a kernel context switch), and to register the alarm signal, but... yeah. A little under once per minute.

Comment: when using tkinter as graphical user interface, sleep() won't do the job - use after() instead: _tkinter.Tk.after(yourrootwindow,60000)_ or _yourrootwindow.after(60000)_

Comment: It is worth mentioning that in Windows the best granularity you can hope for is about 0.015 seconds (15 ms) accuracy.  Most versions of Linux on modern processors can get down to 0.001 seconds (1 ms) granularity.

Comment: @SDsolar What is wrong with sleep: You can't do any processing while it is sleeping, it basically puts the program on hold.

Comment: Indeed.  The tkinter comment would be better presented as an answer instead of in a comment.  We're building a database here that will be around for years to come, with people finding answers via Google, and lots of people never get around to reading the comments.  This would make a great new question, even.  Something along the lines of "How to make a time delay in Python while using tkinter" or similar.

Comment: Yes, but what can be said about the actual time resolution on different platforms? Are there some guarantees? Could the resolution be 16.666 ms?

Comment: @PeterMortensen did you see SDsolar's comment? If you need guarantees you should be using a real time operating system and shouldn't be using a garbage collected language.

Answer (score 871):

Use [`sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep) from the `time` module. It can take a float argument for sub-second resolution.

```
from time import sleep
sleep(0.1)  # Time in seconds
```

Comment: What about the time resolution? E.g., is there a risk of it being a multiple of 16.66 ms (though in the example it would happen to be exactly 0.1 second, 6 multiples of 16.66 ms)? Or is e.g. at least 1 ms guaranteed? For example, could a specified delay of 3 ms actually result in a 17 ms delay?

Comment: maybe printing out some precision (verbose) would be great too? as a future * thing perhaps

Answer (score 112):

> ## How can I make a time delay in Python?

In a single thread I suggest the [sleep function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep):

```
>>> from time import sleep

>>> sleep(4)
```

This function actually suspends the processing of the thread in which it is called by the operating system, allowing other threads and processes to execute while it sleeps.

Use it for that purpose, or simply to delay a function from executing. For example:

```
>>> def party_time():
...     print('hooray!')
...
>>> sleep(3); party_time()
hooray!
```

"hooray!" is printed 3 seconds after I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

#### Example using `sleep` with multiple threads and processes

Again, `sleep` suspends your thread - it uses next to zero processing power.

To demonstrate, create a script like this (I first attempted this in an interactive Python 3.5 shell, but sub-processes can't find the `party_later` function for some reason):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import sleep, time

def party_later(kind='', n=''):
    sleep(3)
    return kind + n + ' party time!: ' + __name__

def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as proc_executor:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as thread_executor:
            start_time = time()
            proc_future1 = proc_executor.submit(party_later, kind='proc', n='1')
            proc_future2 = proc_executor.submit(party_later, kind='proc', n='2')
            thread_future1 = thread_executor.submit(party_later, kind='thread', n='1')
            thread_future2 = thread_executor.submit(party_later, kind='thread', n='2')
            for f in as_completed([
              proc_future1, proc_future2, thread_future1, thread_future2,]):
                print(f.result())
            end_time = time()
    print('total time to execute four 3-sec functions:', end_time - start_time)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example output from this script:

```
thread1 party time!: __main__
thread2 party time!: __main__
proc1 party time!: __mp_main__
proc2 party time!: __mp_main__
total time to execute four 3-sec functions: 3.4519670009613037
```

### Multithreading

You can trigger a function to be called at a later time in a separate thread with the `Timer` [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) object:

```
>>> from threading import Timer
>>> t = Timer(3, party_time, args=None, kwargs=None)
>>> t.start()
>>>
>>> hooray!

>>>
```

The blank line illustrates that the function printed to my standard output, and I had to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to ensure I was on a prompt.

The upside of this method is that while the `Timer` thread was waiting, I was able to do other things, in this case, hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> one time - before the function executed (see the first empty prompt).

There isn't a respective object in the [multiprocessing library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). You can create one, but it probably doesn't exist for a reason. A sub-thread makes a lot more sense for a simple timer than a whole new subprocess.

Answer (score 84):

Delays can be also implemented by using the following methods.

The first method:

```
import time
time.sleep(5) # Delay for 5 seconds.
```

The second method to delay would be using the implicit wait method:

```
 driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

The third method is more useful when you have to wait until a particular action is completed or until an element is found:

```
self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'UserName'))
```

Comment: The second and the third method are not Python per-se, but selenium related. And you'd use them when you're doing E2E tests. OP hasn't mentioned about any of those.

Answer (score 73):

There are five methods which I know: `time.sleep()`, `pygame.time.wait()`, matplotlib's `pyplot.pause()`, `.after()`, and `asyncio.sleep()`.

---

`time.sleep()` example (do not use if using tkinter):

```
import time
print('Hello')
time.sleep(5) # Number of seconds
print('Bye')
```

---

`pygame.time.wait()` example (not recommended if you are not using the pygame window, but you could exit the window instantly):

```
import pygame
# If you are going to use the time module
# don't do "from pygame import *"
pygame.init()
print('Hello')
pygame.time.wait(5000) # Milliseconds
print('Bye')
```

---

matplotlib's function `pyplot.pause()` example (not recommended if you are not using the graph, but you could exit the graph instantly):

```
import matplotlib
print('Hello')
matplotlib.pyplot.pause(5) # Seconds
print('Bye')
```

---

The `.after()` method (best with Tkinter):

```
import tkinter as tk # Tkinter for Python&nbsp;2
root = tk.Tk()
print('Hello')
def ohhi():
    print('Oh, hi!')
root.after(5000, ohhi) # Milliseconds and then a function
print('Bye')
```

---

Finally, the `asyncio.sleep()` method (has to be in an async loop):

```
await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Comment: `driver.implicitly_wait()` is a selenium webdriver method that sets the default wait time for finding elements on a web page. It is totally irrelevant to the question asked.

Comment: That's not how `asyncio.sleep` works. One has to `await` it while inside an event loop. It is not a general purpose delay.

Answer (score 55):

A bit of fun with a sleepy [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

The question is about time delay. It can be fixed time, but in some cases we might need a delay measured since last time. Here is one possible solution:

## Delay measured since last time (waking up regularly)

The situation can be, we want to do something as regularly as possible and we do not want to bother with all the `last_time`, `next_time` stuff all around our code.

### Buzzer generator

The following code (**sleepy.py**) defines a `buzzergen` generator:

```
import time
from itertools import count

def buzzergen(period):
    nexttime = time.time() + period
    for i in count():
        now = time.time()
        tosleep = nexttime - now
        if tosleep > 0:
            time.sleep(tosleep)
            nexttime += period
        else:
            nexttime = now + period
        yield i, nexttime
```

### Invoking regular buzzergen

```
from sleepy import buzzergen
import time
buzzer = buzzergen(3) # Planning to wake up each 3 seconds
print time.time()
buzzer.next()
print time.time()
time.sleep(2)
buzzer.next()
print time.time()
time.sleep(5) # Sleeping a bit longer than usually
buzzer.next()
print time.time()
buzzer.next()
print time.time()
```

And running it we see:

```
1400102636.46
1400102639.46
1400102642.46
1400102647.47
1400102650.47
```

We can also use it directly in a loop:

```
import random
for ring in buzzergen(3):
    print "now", time.time()
    print "ring", ring
    time.sleep(random.choice([0, 2, 4, 6]))
```

And running it we might see:

```
now 1400102751.46
ring (0, 1400102754.461676)
now 1400102754.46
ring (1, 1400102757.461676)
now 1400102757.46
ring (2, 1400102760.461676)
now 1400102760.46
ring (3, 1400102763.461676)
now 1400102766.47
ring (4, 1400102769.47115)
now 1400102769.47
ring (5, 1400102772.47115)
now 1400102772.47
ring (6, 1400102775.47115)
now 1400102775.47
ring (7, 1400102778.47115)
```

As we see, this buzzer is not too rigid and allow us to catch up with regular sleepy intervals even if we oversleep and get out of regular schedule.

Answer (score 35):

The [Tkinter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter) library in the Python standard library is an interactive tool which you can import. Basically, you can create buttons and boxes and popups and stuff that appear as windows which you manipulate with code.

If you use Tkinter, ***do not use `time.sleep()`***, because it will muck up your program. This happened to me. Instead, use `root.after()` and replace the values for however many seconds, with a milliseconds. For example, `time.sleep(1)` is equivalent to `root.after(1000)` in Tkinter.

Otherwise, `time.sleep()`, which many answers have pointed out, which is the way to go.

Answer (score 27):

Delays are done with the [time library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html), specifically the [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) function.

To just make it wait for a second:

```
from time import sleep
sleep(1)
```

This works because by doing:

```
from time import sleep
```

You extract the [sleep function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) **only** from the [time library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html), which means you can just call it with:

```
sleep(seconds)
```

Rather than having to type out

```
time.sleep()
```

Which is awkwardly long to type.

With this method, you wouldn't get access to the other features of the [time library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) and you can't have a variable called `sleep`. But you could create a variable called `time`.

Doing [`from [library] import [function] (, [function2])`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules) is great if you just want certain parts of a module.

You could equally do it as:

```
import time
time.sleep(1)
```

and you would have access to the other features of the [time library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) like [`time.clock()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock) as long as you type `time.[function]()`, but you couldn't create the variable time because it would overwrite the import. A solution to this to do

```
import time as t
```

which would allow you to reference the [time library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) as `t`, allowing you to do:

```
t.sleep()
```

This works on any library.

Comment: this is basically a mini tutorial on imports, which the OP never asked about.   This answer could be replaced with "use `time.sleep()`"

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I dont see any harm in this post, it  explains a bit imports too!

Answer (score 16):

#### If you would like to put a time delay in a Python script:

Use **`time.sleep`** or **`Event().wait`** like this:

```
from threading import Event
from time import sleep

delay_in_sec = 2

# Use time.sleep like this
sleep(delay_in_sec)         # Returns None
print(f'slept for {delay_in_sec} seconds')

# Or use Event().wait like this
Event().wait(delay_in_sec)  # Returns False
print(f'waited for {delay_in_sec} seconds')
```

## However, if you want to delay the execution of a function do this:

Use [**`threading.Timer`**](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html?highlight=timer#threading.Timer) like this:

```
from threading import Timer

delay_in_sec = 2

def hello(delay_in_sec):
    print(f'function called after {delay_in_sec} seconds')

t = Timer(delay_in_sec, hello, [delay_in_sec])  # Hello function will be called 2 seconds later with [delay_in_sec] as the *args parameter
t.start()  # Returns None
print("Started")
```

Outputs:

```
Started
function called after 2 seconds
```

#### Why use the later approach?

- It does **not** stop execution of the whole script (except for the function you pass it).
- After starting the timer you can also stop it by doing `timer_obj.cancel()`.

Comment: its working for the first time.. second time its giving error 'RuntimeError: threads can only be started once'

Answer (score 12):

### asyncio.sleep

Notice in recent Python versions (Python 3.4 or higher) you can use `asyncio.sleep`. It's related to asynchronous programming and asyncio. Check out next example:

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

@asyncio.coroutine
def countdown(iteration_name, countdown_sec):
    """
    Just count for some countdown_sec seconds and do nothing else
    """
    while countdown_sec > 0:
       print(f'{iteration_name} iterates: {countdown_sec} seconds')
       yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
       countdown_sec -= 1

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(countdown('First Count', 2)),
         asyncio.ensure_future(countdown('Second Count', 3))]

start_time = datetime.utcnow()

# Run both methods. How much time will both run...?
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))

loop.close()

print(f'total running time: {datetime.utcnow() - start_time}')
```

We may think it will "sleep" for 2 seconds for first method and then 3 seconds in the second method, a total of 5 seconds running time of this code. But it will print:

```
total_running_time: 0:00:03.01286
```

It is recommended to read [asyncio official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) for more details.

Comment: Why is this better than time.sleep()?

Comment: Try running similar example with `time.sleep`. You will not get same running time results. Recommend to read about `asynchronous` programming in python

Comment: The original question was about inserting a delay. That nail needs a hammer, not an asynchronous wrench :-)

Answer (score 8):

While everyone else has suggested the de facto `time` module, I thought I'd share a different method using `matplotlib`'s `pyplot` function, [`pause`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html).

#### An example

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.pause(5)    # Pauses the program for 5 seconds
```

Typically this is used to prevent the plot from disappearing as soon as it is plotted or to make crude animations.

This would save you an `import` if you already have `matplotlib` imported.

Answer (score 7):

This is an easy example of a time delay:

```
import time

def delay(period='5'):
    # If the user enters nothing, it'll wait 5 seconds
    try:
        # If the user not enters a int, I'll just return ''
        time.sleep(period)
    except:
        return ''
```

Another, in [Tkinter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter):

```
import tkinter

def tick():
    pass

root = Tk()
delay = 100 # Time in milliseconds
root.after(delay, tick)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2):

You also can try this:

```
import time
# The time now
start = time.time() 
while time.time() - start < 10: # Run 1- seconds
    pass
# Do the job
```

Now the shell will not crash or not react.

Comment: Don't use this solution. It may technically work, but it will eat your CPU. Modern hardware and operating systems have better ways of creating time delays that don't hog system resources. Use time.sleep() instead.

Comment: Yes, modern, like anything from the last 4-5 decades.