# new to Python, help with loops

Tags: python, websocket, mod-python

i have this opensource code which is used to echo back response to web-socket requests:

```
_GOODBYE_MESSAGE = 'Goodbye'


def web_socket_do_extra_handshake(request):
    pass  # Always accept.


def web_socket_transfer_data(request):
while True:
    line = request.ws_stream.receive_message()
    if line == "hello":
        request.ws_stream.send_message("hello was sent")
    if line == "bye":
        request.ws_stream.send_message("bye was sent")
    if line is None:
        return
    #request.ws_stream.send_message(line)

    if line == _GOODBYE_MESSAGE:
        return
```

now problem is i want to modify it (transfer_data method) so that inside the while loop lets say it checks the string line if it equals certains text, it should return something else to client and if line equals something else it shoud return a different string.
I have tried lot but it does not seem to work, i know it is very basic, but can someone please help me with this.
Another thing i want to do is to be able to add delay to response say 5 seconds, but import time does not work. I get error, please help with this.

Comment: Can you post the code that didn't work?

Comment: Ok i have modified it, i used something like the one i showed above. I am not familiar with python syntax, but what could be wrong with this? Also how can i add delay in printing result??

Comment: What error message does the above code give you? (Besides the indentation issue between the def line and the beginning of the while loop, which I assume isn't in the original code) Also, FYI you can probably use an "if...elif...elif" structure for checking what line is rather than "if...if...if".

Comment: Hi, actually it is working, i was confused with double errors. I want to add time delay but where should i put this import time, time.sleep(5) statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for your first question, you can just say

```
if line == "whatever":
   # do stuff here, return, whatever...
   request.ws_stream.send_message(line)
else:
   # do something else....
```

for sleeping, you want

```
 import time
 time.sleep(seconds)
```

if the "import time" line fails, you've got a problem with your python interpreter configuration.

Comment: thank you, the first part works, but the time sleep function has problems, it does not work

Comment: Another SO question that talks about python's time.sleep(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python

Comment: [2011-07-25 19:40:43,058] [WARNING] root: mod_pywebsocket: ../example/echo_wsh.py: Error in sourcing handler:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\mod_pywebsocket\dispatch.py", line 120, in _source_handler_file
    exec handler_definition in global_dic
  File "<string>", line 44
     request.ws_stream.send_message("hello was sent")
                                                    ^
 IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: this is the error that i get when i use sleep func anywhere inside if condition.

Comment: that error means your spacing is incorrect. python cares about whitespace, your time.sleep line must be indented the same as everything else inside your loop.

Comment: Don't use `is` to check for equality, string or otherwise.

Comment: the spacing is perfectly fine. i don't understand why would it be related to indentation??

Comment: the error you posted is an indentation error on line 44: line 44 request.ws_stream.send_message("hello was sent") ^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: this is strange, because if i remove the time.sleep statement while leave import time statement at the start, there is NO error. But with this time.sleep i get this error. Can you please help me

Comment: HI PROBLEM IS SOLVED. IT WAS THE PLACEMENT OF TIME.SLEEP I WAS PUTTING IT IN IF CONDITION AND IT DID NOT WORK. WHEN I PUT IT RIGHT AFTER WHILE IT WORKS. THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP

Answer (score 0):

For the control logic, look at the Python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html) (link is to 2.7).

Note you can modify your if structure to something like this:

```
def web_socket_transfer_data(request):
    while True: # This was at the wrong indent - check it was a copy-paste issue
        line = request.ws_stream.receive_message()

        if line is "hello":
            request.ws_stream.send_message("hello was sent")
        elif line is "bye": # elif is the Pythonic form of else if
            request.ws_stream.send_message("bye was sent")
        elif line is _GOODBYE_MESSAGE or line is None:
            break # This exits the while loop and by extension the method

        time.sleep(5)
```

As for the issue with [time.sleep()](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep), you'll want to make sure you do `import time` at the beginning of the file. If that doesn't work you might want to check if you can import it directly through IDLE. That is, run IDLE and type `import time`. If that fails, please post the error it returns.

Comment: with IDLE, there is no error. It accepts the command.
I use import time at the start of this file. but still it gives following error on cmd line:

Comment: [2011-07-25 19:48:39,503] [WARNING] root: mod_pywebsocket: ../example/echo_wsh.py: Error in sourcing handler:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\mod_pywebsocket\dispatch.py", line 120, in _source_handler_file
    exec handler_definition in global_dic
  File "<string>", line 43
     request.ws_stream.send_message("hello was sent")
                                                    ^
 IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: @Johnydep That last bit is the relevant part. The `IndentationError` means it's seeing something strange in your whitespace at line 43 - make sure your `while` loop is indented once from the method definition and that the if statements are two indents deep, with their actions 3 deep. Assuming you've place `time.sleep` about where I did it should be 2 deep (on the level with the if statements). Double-check there isn't mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: i don't know. I just moved time.sleep from inside of if to right after while and now everything is working fine.

Comment: @Johnydep Sounds like it was definitely something at a different indent reacting oddly.