# How to make time delays in Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make a time delay in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python)

In Python, how can you make things delay? Like in RBLX.lua, you go "wait(3)" and the current script would delay for 3 seconds. How can you do that in Python?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for a 3 second delay:

```
import time
time.sleep(3)
```