# Google api limitation overcome

Tags: python-2.7

Hi all we are using google api for e.g. this one 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query via python script but very fast it gets blocked. Any work around for this? Thank you.

Below is my current codes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math,sys
import json
import urllib

def gsearch(searchfor):
  query = urllib.urlencode({'q': searchfor})
  url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query
  search_response = urllib.urlopen(url)
  search_results = search_response.read()
  results = json.loads(search_results)
  data = results['responseData']
  return data

args = sys.argv[1:]
m = 45000000000
if len(args) != 2:
        print "need two words as arguments"
        exit
n0 = int(gsearch(args[0])['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
n1 = int(gsearch(args[1])['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
n2 = int(gsearch(args[0]+" "+args[1])['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link doesn't work, and there is no code here, so all I can suggest is finding out from the API what the limits are, and [delaying your requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python) appropriately. Alternatively, you can probably pay for less restricted API usage.

Comment: I have added my codes. I dont run immediately I pause for each run.

Answer (score 1):

1. Link is bad.
2. Usually you can overcome this by paying for use.

Comment: Wow that is going to be too long for me. Any other option?