# Run certain code every x seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

please tell me how to make sure that the function printit () is executed every second?

```
import threading

def printit():
    print("Hello, World!")    

threading.Timer(1.0, printit).start()
```

the problem is that the 'hello world' appears only once

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python/510351#510351

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('Hello world')
```