# Python Hello World keeps closing itself

Tags: python

I'm new to programming. I''ve successfully wrote everybody's first program , however , it executes right before closing itself. How can I add a pause to the program?

Comment: Can you show what you have written so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the code to be like this, you will learn about the below function soon enough:

```
print('Hello world!')
input()
```

Now at the end of the program it won't exit until you press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Or better still, run the code in a shell like IDLE so you don't have to worry about all that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a call to [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) at the bottom of your script:

```
print("Hello World!")

input("Press 'Enter' to exit.") # Use raw_input in Python 2.x
```

Doing so will keep the output window open until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally want to add a fixed pause, use the `sleep` function in the `time` module. The is discussed in detail in the answer to [How can I make a time delay in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python) . Your program then becomes:

```
import time
print("Hello world")
time.sleep(1)
```

The first line tells python that `time` means the module `time`, while the last line says to wait for 1 second. (If you wanted to wait for 2.5 seconds, then change the last line to `time.sleep(2.5)`, etc...)

Comment: I suppose sleep function is more complex than input function?

Comment: @Harmone - `time.sleep` will wait for as long as you tell it, then the window will close.  `input` will keep the window open until you press a key.