# Pause and resume a function

Tags: python, multithreading, random, artificial-intelligence

I'm writing a bot in python and to "humanize" it I need to pause and resume functions randomly.
Functions can be paused and resumed only at some defined points.

The bot is made of various functions, like

```
do_action1(*args)
do_action2(*args)
do_action3(*args)
...
start_bot()
stop_bot()
```

The function `start_bot()` calls `do_action1()`, `do_action2()`, ... in order and gives them `*args`.
I need to find a way to start a `do_actionX()` function randomly and at some points pause it and run another random `do_actionX()` function then pause it and resume the previous one and so on...

To start a function randomly I thought I can use a dictionary with functions inside and pick one of them randomly.

I think I can do this with threads, but since my bot is using multiprocessing, would it be a right choice to use multithreading and multiprocessing together?
I use multiprocessing to run multiple bots at the same time and manage them from a main Python script which is linked to an interface. Each bot instance connects to a different account.

If I use multithreading, how can I make the function stop at some defined points and not randomly?

For example:

```
def do_action1(*args):
     print("something")
     # do something else
     # <--- at this point the function could be paused
     print("something")
     # <--- at this pint the function cannot be paused!
     print("else")
     # <--- and here the function could be paused again
```

The times that a function will be paused must be random. Is there a way to do this?
Are threads the right approach to this issue?

Comment: Why not use yield inside the function to pause? And recall the same function if no other function needs to run. This would make it one thread per bot

Comment: See [A Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `yield` keyword to create co-routines. Here is one example:

```
import random
random.seed()

def do_action1():
    print("Hello")
    yield
    print("HELLO!")
    yield
    print("hello?")
def do_action2():
    print("Are you there?")
    yield
    print("ARE YOU THERE!")
    yield
    print("I'm scared.")
def do_action3():
    print("Is somebody out there?")
    yield
    print("SOMEBODY IS OUT THERE!")
    yield
    print("I'm dead.")

def bot(*actions):
    actions = [action() for action in actions]
    while actions:
        action = random.choice(actions)
        try:
            next(action)
        except StopIteration:
            actions.remove(action)
    return

bot(do_action1, do_action2, do_action3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Threads are one good way to do it. To pause the function, use [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep), (based on [How can I make a time delay in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python)):

```
import time, random

# Time range to sleep, in seconds
def randomWait():
    sleepMin = 1.0
    sleepMax = 5.0
    time.sleep(random.uniform(sleepMin, sleepMax))

def do_action1(*args):
    print("something")
    # do something else
    randomWait()
    print("something")
    print("else")
    randomWait()
```

I used [`random.uniform`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform) in this example, but you are free to make the randomness of the interval as fancy as you would like using the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module or anything else you like.

A threaded solution will allow different actions to run simultaneouly. If you do not want to allow this, use a single thread and use `yield` as user1827356 suggests:

```
import time, random

# Time range to sleep, in seconds
def randomWait():
    sleepMin = 1.0
    sleepMax = 5.0
    time.sleep(random.uniform(sleepMin, sleepMax))

def do_action1(*args):
    print("something")
    # do something else
    yield
    print("something")
    print("else")

# Other actions defined similarly

actions = [do_action1(), do_action2(), do_action3()]
while actions:
    randomWait()
    action = random.choice(actions)
    try:
        next(action)
    except StopIteration:
        actions.remove(action)
```

Note that in this case your actions are generators. They are basically objects that run the code you define and store the state (pause) whenever they hit a `yield` keyword. For a single-threaded application, this is probably the best way to go.

Comment: You've not copied @Robᵩ's answer correctly. You don't called the actions so they never get to the first `yield`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I did not copy Rob although he did post that part first. My answer had the StopIteration catch before his was edited.