# APScheduler repeat jobs after previous run has finished

Tags: python, apscheduler

I'm running two jobs with [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) with GeventScheduler. But I want this jobs to run with pause, for example 1 minute and after the previous run has finished all tasks repeat this jobs. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How about adding a [sleep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python) to the end of the first script?

Comment: They have to work asynchronically and process a lot of data, so I even don't know how long script should sleep between two runs.

Answer (score 2):

This is worked for me

```
def execution_listener(event):
    job_id = event.job_id
    if event.exception:
        logging.error('job_id={} error!'.format(event.job_id))
    else:
        logging.info('job_id={} success'.format(event.job_id))
        # check that the executed job is the first job
        if job_id == CONST.JOB_ID.WORKEXP_CUT:   
             run_job_now(job_id, arg_dict)# run ypur job


def run_job_now(job_id, arg_dict):
    logging.info('id={} start'.format(job_id))
    job = scheduler.get_job(job_id)
    if job:
        job.modify(next_run_time=datetime.datetime.now())
    else:
        scheduler.add_job(next_run_time=datetime.datetime.now(), **arg_dict) 

scheduler.add_listener(execution_listener, EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED | EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
```