# openCV : Detect object without displaying the webcam view window

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, haar-classifier, eye-detection

I am using Haar cascade classifiers to detect eyes from the webcam. I don't want to display what the webcam is capturing. 
This is part of a project for eye movement analysis. I want to know where on screen the user is looking. 
if I display the window showing their face, they inevitably tend to look only at that part of the screen where this window is.

I tried removing the statement

```
cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
```

But the next statement

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
  break
```

seems to be causing a problem. 
So I replaced it with

```
cv2.waitKey(delay=5000)
  break
```

But it does not wait for the specified delay time and goes on to executing the next statements, which I do not want.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?
I am using python 2.7.9 and openCV 2.4.9

Comment: I figured out a way. These statement were within a loop. `while (cap.isOpened()):` 
I added a counter instead and by a simple increment statement it worked!
`while (incr<100):`
That's giving me enough values for tracing the eye movement.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) states about the `waitKey` command:

> Note: The function only works if there is at least one HighGUI window
>   created and the window is active. If there are several HighGUI
>   windows, any of them can be active.

So you can either open a window that does show something other than the current image of the webcam or use [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python) `sleep` command to wait for a specified time.