# clicker eats a lot of processor time - python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, pyautogui

I have a simple program that does the following:
1) User points a mouse somewhere, 
2) then user presses Space, 
3) and computer does certain amount of left-botton-mouse-clicks at that point.

The program works fine, there is only one problem - it eats 30-50% of processor time on a 4-core processor. Where is the problem?

```
import pyautogui
import ctypes

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True

def get_space_state():
    hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL ("User32.dll")
    VK_SPACE = 0x20
    return hllDll.GetKeyState(VK_SPACE)

while True:
    if get_space_state() == -127 or get_space_state() == -128:
        print ("yes")
        pyautogui.click(clicks=40 , interval=0.01)
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Correct answer**: I suspect a constant polling because of `while True:`. Insert [sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python) or [pyautogui.PAUSE](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html?highlight=PAUSE) there (inside while loop, before `if`), if process sleeps for a while (even less then a second) it frees a lot of CPU cycles

**Minor optimizations**:
Also you're initializing entire User32.dll in every loop... twice (because of `or`), it seems.
And User32 is [HUGE](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/21848-functions-in-user32dll/)

**Hints and notes**:

If I remember python rules right, you just can move `hllDll` to a module level (above function defintion), `get_space_state()` will find it anyway. Or you can pass it as a parameter. And you don't need to redefine VK_SPACE every function call - though this is a micro-optimization

If all these fixes won't work, you should use debuggers, to find a true source of slowdowns

If you happen to have problems like this in the future, use something like [Immunity](https://www.immunityinc.com/products/debugger/) or [WinDbg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) to attach to process and see what's going on there

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1) How and where should I insert "sleep"? 2) about "twice" - I changed to "if get_space_state() < 0:" - nothing improved. 3) Do you know the way to initialize NOT entire User32.dll - but the only needed part of it?

Comment: sadly, though, no, I don't know how to export a single function, but it will not matter much if you'll just export lib once - on loading

Comment: You are RIGHT. The problem is solved with only one line: "time.sleep(0.02)" inserted before "if". Everything else doesn't matter at all.

Comment: It could matter but only on a very high-load processing, I guess, which is not an option for a simple clicker :)