# python program start time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

i have a raspberry pi 3 (os:rasbian) and i want to run this code for exp at 13:00
when i leave the at home 12:00 but i want program will start 1 hour later.
how can i modify the program.
thanks

```
import time
import picamera
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.start_preview()
    try:
        for i, filename in enumerate(camera.capture_continuous('/home/pi/Google Drive/{timestamp:%H-%M-%S}-{counter:03d}.jpg')):
            print(filename)
            time.sleep(3)
            if i == 3:
                break
    finally:
        camera.stop_preview()
```

Comment: Try adding a sleep command to the program start within the python program?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python

Comment: Or do "sleep 3600 && python ..." in bash so you don't have to change the code itself.

Comment: @the-run Please be very careful about changing formatting of Python code. Your edit caused a syntax error.

Comment: Maybe you should use **cron** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
import time
import picamera

# Pause program until Enter is pressed (press when You leave the home)
start = raw_input('Press Enter to start the counter: ') # or input(), if You use Python3

# Show message
print('Camera will start recording in 1 hour')

# Capture Ctrl-C
try:

    # Sleep for an hour
    time.sleep(3600)

# Maybe You want to start immediately, pressed Ctrl-C
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Starting camera now')

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.start_preview()
    try:
        for i, filename in enumerate(camera.capture_continuous('/home/pi/Google Drive/{timestamp:%H-%M-%S}-{counter:03d}.jpg')):
            print(filename)
            time.sleep(3)
            if i == 3:
                break
    finally:
        camera.stop_preview()
```

This way, You can start program anytime You want and let it wait in the background. You activate it before You leave. You can also force it to start immediately if You need.

Comment: Sleep for an hour
    time.sleep(3600)

it works thank you very much

Comment: if you can edit please change time.sleep(3600) thanks