# Script uses too many cpu power when run as a service on a Raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, systemd

I have this code snippet running on a raspberry pi. It basically take pictures of people coming in and out of my room.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GP
import os
import socket


def opencallback(channel):
    print(GP.input(channel))
    if GP.input(channel):

        global closeEvent
        closeEvent = 1
    else:
        global openEvent
        openEvent = 1


def transmit(message):
    s = socket.create_connection((host, port))
    s.send(message)
    s.close()


def capture(cam, gpiolist, quick):
    GP.output(cam1, gpiolist[0])
    GP.output(cam2, gpiolist[1])
    GP.output(cam3, gpiolist[2])

    if quick:
        cmd = "raspistill -o capture_%d.jpg -t 2" % cam
    else:
        cmd = "raspistill -o capture_%d.jpg" % cam
    os.system(cmd)


# init
GP.setwarnings(False)
GP.setmode(GP.BOARD)

cam1 = 7
cam2 = 11
cam3 = 12
doorIn = 40
ledOut = 38

GP.setup(cam1, GP.OUT)  # camera Mux1
GP.setup(cam2, GP.OUT)  # camera Mux2
GP.setup(cam3, GP.OUT)  # camera Mux3
GP.setup(ledOut, GP.OUT)  # LED OUT GPIO 20
GP.setup(doorIn, GP.IN)  # Door detector in GPIO 21

GP.add_event_detect(doorIn, GP.BOTH, callback=opencallback)

GP.output(ledOut, False)
openEvent = 0
closeEvent = 0
host = '192.168.1.111'
port = 13579

# main
while True:
    if openEvent == 1:
        transmit("2-01")
        capture(2, (False, True, False), True)  # front cam
        transmit("2-03")
        openEvent = 0
    else:
        pass

    if closeEvent == 1:
        transmit("2-02")
        GP.output(ledOut, True)
        capture(3, (False, False, True), False)
        GP.output(ledOut, False)
        transmit("2-04")
        closeEvent = 0
    else:
        pass
```

Usually, I run it simply by using a standard call through command line and it doesn't load out the system.

However, I recently converted it to a service using systemd/ systemctl because I wanted to load that script in the background when I boot the pi. Now, this script is gulping a whole processor core by itself (as reported by htop). I didn't change anything to the code itself during the transition and when I run it the old way, it is still working okay. Most of the time, it is simply running the while loop doing nothing and waiting for a callback from GPIO and then execute some functions and go back to the while pass behavior.

My question is: what is causing the difference in computing power consumption between the two execution methods? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you execute the process with `nice` ?

Comment: Trying using [`time.sleep`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python). This will pause the thread and let your CPU do other things (including nothing)

Comment: I could include time.sleep and I will probably miss any events, but it doesn't explain the major difference in computing power required. 

I'm also not sure what is nice.

Comment: @Slylandro, I don't see how this would *ever* be CPU-efficient, no matter how you run it. Being in a tight loop that does continuous polling is *always* an expensive operation. I almost wonder if the version you tested with from the command line did something like logging to console (and, by association, causing the process to block until that output could be written) that effectively enforced a delay.

Comment: Linux kernel has the ability to grant priority to certain processes.  This is called the "niceness" of a process.  It is possible to set the niceness of systemd resources, and it may be running with a different niceness as a systemd resource than as a cli application.  https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync/issues/205
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)

Comment: @Scott, that's true, but a `nice`'d process will still use all available CPU, so it'll still be "gulping a whole processor core", as the OP is complaining about.

Comment: *This is just one possibility, that I think @JacobIRR was pointing out

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I had assumed that by "gulping the whole cpu", the problem was that other processes were not running properly, because this program was using up all the resources and not sharing.  Changing the niceness would help with that thing.

Comment: @Charles I wholly agree with that. Usually, when doing embedded programming (e.g on a arduino), there is a way to ''wake up'' the uC using an external IO. It will also react correctly to those type of loops.

To answer your question, my GPIO pins are connected to a camera multiplexer and to a magnetic door detector. It needs not to react that fast. I tested the delay it indeed helps out.

Regarding your second part,  you're probably right about the fact that running it natively cause a natural delay that systemd doesn't execute.

Comment: @Scott actually, it makes the RPi slightly overheat since it is inside an enclosed space.

Comment: If both `openEvent` and `closeEvent` are not equal to 1, your code doesn't run any edge-detection/blocking code at all, so it's expected for it to be a tight loop that does nothing but eat CPU.

Comment: ...if you want to only run events when triggered by a callback, *do that*, and take out the endless loop.

Comment: @Charles openEvent and closeEvent are set to 1 during a callback of the GPIO. This is usually how it is done when doing embedded programming (you can clearly guess that my experience and reflex are based on embedded programming and not on system programming). 

Now the question is therefore, if I only want to run it via callback, I still need the script to continue running in some capacity until the callback occurs. 

The easy way out is via time.sleep. Odds are that you will not miss an event. Otherwise, I guess it requires a change in the code that is outside of my current knowledge.

Comment: At the very least, the answer that you provided is quite elegant for my needs and will be in my knowledge base for the time being. Most of the embedded code that I wrote in the past (be it for work, or undergrad studies) didn't really tax the system or anything. Therefore, I might have gone lazy in my way of thinking simply because I never hit any snag. I don't have you're level of experience in embedded dev mostly because I'm still young in my career. 

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edge-detection/callback code is efficient, only being invoked when an event takes place. However, the top-level `while True:` loop is *extremely* inefficient.

Consider the following modifications:

```
try:
    import Queue as queue # Python 2.x
except ImportError:
    import queue          # Python 3.x

eventQueue = queue.Queue()

def opencallback(channel):
    eventQueue.put(GP.input(channel))

# ...your existing setup code here, specifically including:
GP.add_event_detect(doorIn, GP.BOTH, callback=opencallback)

while True:
    event = eventQueue.get()
    if event:
        transmit("2-01")
        capture(2, (False, True, False), True)  # front cam
        transmit("2-03")
    else:
        transmit("2-02")
        GP.output(ledOut, True)
        capture(3, (False, False, True), False)
        GP.output(ledOut, False)
        transmit("2-04")
```

Note that *this is not related to systemd* -- you would have the same CPU usage issues with any other invocation method as well.

Comment: Ooh, I really like that! I completely forgot Python had a readily available Queue library. However, does this give the CPU a ready opportunity to switch away the way that time.sleep does?

Comment: @Ketzak, yes, it does.

Comment: All my other scripts that I wrote didn't have that problem since they were actually polling for a socket connection to happens in a similar way than this one. I took the time to implement it correctly tonight and, yes it solves the problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the callbacks trigger the actions for open and close events directly? Just have the loop run a short time.sleep

```
def opencallback(channel):
    print(GP.input(channel))
    if GP.input(channel):
        transmit("2-02")
        GP.output(ledOut, True)
        capture(3, (False, False, True), False)
        GP.output(ledOut, False)
        transmit("2-04")
        closeEvent = 0
    else:
        transmit("2-01")
        capture(2, (False, True, False), True)  # front cam
        transmit("2-03")
```

Comment: Short answer: because that way you cue the process and don't stay too long on the callback (taking the picture take a few seconds and I could miss the second callback)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.