# How to add timed delay in Python for hardware control

Tags: python, time, raspberry-pi

I have managed to construct some python code on a Raspberry PI to control a garage door. However I don't know how to add a timed delay so that the control is limited to the correct movement time.

Any help would be appreciated.

My working code is below.

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO          
    from time import sleep

    in1 = 24
    in2 = 23
    en = 25
    temp1=1

   GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
   GPIO.setup(in1,GPIO.OUT)
   GPIO.setup(in2,GPIO.OUT)
   GPIO.setup(en,GPIO.OUT)
   GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
   GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
   p=GPIO.PWM(en,1000)
   p.start(25)
   print("\n")
   print("The default speed & direction of motor is LOW & Forward.....")
   print("r-run s-stop f-forward b-backward l-low m-medium h-high e-exit")
   print("\n")    

   while(1):
   x = input()
   if x=='r':
   print("run")
   if(temp1==1):
   GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.HIGH)
   GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
   print("forward")
   x='z'
   else:
   GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
   GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.HIGH)
   print("backward")
   x='z'


   elif x=='s':
   print("stop")
   GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
   GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
   x='z'

   elif x=='f':
   print("forward")
   GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.HIGH)
   GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.LOW)
   temp1=1
   x='z'

   elif x=='b':
   print("backward")
   GPIO.output(in1,GPIO.LOW)
   GPIO.output(in2,GPIO.HIGH)
   temp1=0
   x='z'

   elif x=='l':
   print("low")
   p.ChangeDutyCycle(25)
   x='z'

   elif x=='m':
   print("medium")
   p.ChangeDutyCycle(50)
   x='z'

   elif x=='h':
   print("high")
   p.ChangeDutyCycle(75)
   x='z'


    elif x=='e':
    GPIO.cleanup()
    break

    else:
    print("<<<  wrong data  >>>")
    print("please enter the defined data to continue.....")
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't help with PI code but would like to add a little warning. If you rely on time to switch off the motor then any cars, kids, bikes etc would be crushed by the closing door. Can you interface a current sensor to the Pie so that it stops when the motor current exceeds a certain amount? Have a look at [These](https://www.pololu.com/category/118/current-sensors)

Mike.

Comment: Yes thank you, I am aware and plan on adding that feature in the future.

Comment: Good call on that sensor!

Answer (score 0):

This question and answer [How can I make a time delay in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python) shows how to add a timed delay in your code.

```
import time
# delay for 10 seconds
time.sleep(10)
```

However this is not the best solution. Better to use the solutions here : https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69640/add-delay-between-two-gpio-output and I'd also suggest you use pins to capture information such as open or closed from the door perhaps using sensors switches (of which there are various types).