# How to process a big list with interval (5 minutes) after processing 30 elements?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

`list = [40000 elements]`

After processing first 30 elements need to pause for 5 minutes and then start processing again the next 30 element from the list.

```
a = list(set(proflinks))
a = sorted(a) # list a has 40000 elements
a=a[0:30]
#print(a)
for b in a:
    inedex = a.index(b)
    print('profile____' + str(inedex) + '____is processing')
    profileMeta(driver,b)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a time delay in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python)

Comment: @ScottMcC, this dupe suggestion is pretty weak...

Comment: profileMeta will process first 30 elements. after that it will rest for 5 minutes and continue processing another 30 elements.  this process will be continued until the list is empty.

Comment: You can set the `delay` parameter in the `custom_setting` before parsing the url.

Comment: @StephenRauch I disagree. The solution to this problem isn't any more complicated than inserting a `time.sleep()` command at the correct point.

Comment: @ScottMcC, yes but...  The duplicate indicates how to sleep.  So what?  It does not indicate how to sleep at the appropriate point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`%`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) to decide when to sleep like:

```
import time 
a = sorted(set(proflinks)) # list a has 40000 elements
for idx, b in enumerate(a):
    print('profile____{}____is processing'.format(idx)
    profileMeta(driver, b)
    if not ((idx + 1) % 30):
        time.sleep(600)
```