# How to get current timestamp in runtime

Tags: manim

There are three statements like below:

```
print("first time", time.time())
self.wait(5)
print("second time", time.time())
```

I suppose the difference between "second time" and "first time" will be 5 seconds, however, they are the same, why?

I think the self.wait(5) should be async call, if so, how to get timestame in runtime?

Comment: You can try time.sleep(5) if you are importing the time module.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to print in the terminal the exact second of each moment of the animation you can do something like this (the time is saved in the variable self.time):

```py
class TimeTest(Scene):
    def print_time(self):
        print("Time:",self.time)

    def construct(self):
        dot=Dot()
        # 0 seconds
        self.print_time()
        self.play(Write(dot,run_time=2))
        # 2 seconds
        self.print_time()
        self.wait()
        # 3 seconds
        self.print_time()
        self.play(dot.shift,UP,run_time=1)
        # 4 seconds
        self.print_time()
        self.play(FadeToColor(dot,RED,run_time=3))
        # 7 seconds
        self.print_time()
        self.wait()
        # 8 seconds
        self.print_time()
```

Comment: I don't think this exists in the current version

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the recent version of Manim-CE `time` is no longer a member variable of `Scene` (although this might still be the way to go for ManimGL).

What worked for me was using `self.renderer.time`