# How should I delivery my message daily? I want to delay about 10 secs, so how should I edit code?

Tags: chatbot

1.I have to use the same function like manychat's smart delay. But I write the chatbot code with fbmq, which is used the python language. so In this code, I want to delay 10 secs, and then use page_send(response.id,"link") to the users. How should I code that?

```
@page.callback(['test4'])   
def callback_clicked_button(payload, event):
    recipient_id = event.sender_id
    page.send(recipient_id, "Before 10 secs" )

time_sleep(10)
     page.send(recipient_id, "link" )
```

there's no response!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a time delay in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This python time has `sleep` fucntion which will help in delay.

```
import time
time.sleep(5) # 5 stand for seconds
```

Your code will go like this

```
import time

@page.callback(['test4'])   
def callback_clicked_button(payload, event):
    recipient_id = event.sender_id
    page.send(recipient_id, "Before 10 secs" )
    time.sleep(10)
    #time_sleep(10) 
    page.send(recipient_id, "link" )
```