# Can flask g be used with gunicorn?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, race-condition

When flask g keep data on one request and another request follow almost simultaneously (race condition). Will flask g be replaced by new flask g?. And how i can handle if this situation happen. Thank you.

Comment: That should be easy to test.

Comment: One simple way to test this is to add a call to [sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64486) in your code and write a test that makes two requests in quick-enough succession. A somewhat better way is to make the request handler tell the test that it's started and then wait to proceed, perhaps using mocking. Goog luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is no problem. In flask every simultaneous request will be handled in a separate process. There will be multiple `g` at a given time (depending on how you configure gunicorn) but every process will have it's own instance.