# Python while loop be executed in time interval

Tags: python, while-loop

I wanted to use while loop to keep executing my script over and over but there is a problem as my code calls an API that doesn't allow so many calls in small time so I wanted to make the while loop be executed at time interval so I tried this code

```
from threading import Timer
def myfunc():
   some code
while True:
   t = Timer(1.0, myfunc)
   t.start()
```

but it doesn't work, so is there any other way to do it correctly?

Comment: You can try [time.sleep](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time/sleep)

Comment: Just `time.sleep(seconds)` after each call to the API

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a time delay in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `time` module:

```
import time

def myfunc():
   some code

while True:
   myfunc()

   # unit is in second. Example below wait for 1 second before continuing
   time.sleep(1)
```