# Make Python program wait an amount of time

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, pygame, delay

I want my python program to wait before continuing  the loop. But the other functions, loops usw. should work. If I use the sleep-function the whole program would sleep. Example:

```
import pygame

def function():
   print("You moved forward")

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(function, "f")

print("use f to move forward")
(Wait 5 seconds, so the player can try pressing f and sees what happens)
```

Thats a simple version of my original code. I want the player to try WASD cause the character is moved with WASD.

If I'd use time.sleep() it won't work if the player presses f.

Thanks for any answer :D

-> btw sry for my bad english...

Comment: I want make a tutorial for a game. The player is moved with WASD so there should be a text "press WASD to move". Then the player has some seconds time to press WASD and move around.

Comment: what about ```input()```. this will wait until the player presses Enter

Comment: Sorry, it should be a comment, but I can't comment :(
Try this :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48111882/12658348

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait for 5 seconds but not sleep then you can maybe try with a loop and measure the running time of the loop. Something like this maybe:

First make sure pytictoc is installed by running `pip install pytictoc`

Then run a loop like this maybe:

```
from pytictoc import TicToc
t = TicToc() #create instance of class
t.tic() #Start timer
while (t.tocvalue()<5):
    pass
t.toc()
```

Comment: There is an error:

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file test.py on line 141, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
MyNames-MacBook-Pro:rpg username$

Comment: I'll need to see more of your code to see if this error is from this code or not. It is possible that it is related to something else perhaps.

Comment: I tried it in a other document and there was no error. But it works just like time.sleep(), the screen gets paused. Functions aren't working. Here's my code:

import turtle
from pytictoc import TicToc

#Add a function

def testfunc():
    print("Key pressed")
turtle.listen()

#First message
print("test")

#timer
t = TicToc() #create instance of class
t.tic() #Start timer
while (t.tocvalue()<5):
    pass
t.toc()

#Second message
print("test2")

#Keyboard

turtle.onkey(testfunc, "x")

delay = raw_input("Press enter to finish")

I want that the function still works