# How to pause a script in python temporarily?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I am running a code that will take next 2 days to spit out the output. sometime inbetween I would like to use it for other purposes like playing graphic intensive games and running MATLAB. I would like to know is there a way to pause and unpause the code in Spyder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a time delay in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python)

Comment: I cannot believe there isn't a Python equivalent for this. What could prevent an ide to embed this feature?