# How to delay a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wait

I've made a tic tac toe game which basiclly whenever a player wins,the script waits five seconds and quits itself.
I searched it on google and it said I could use `time.sleep()`.
But the problem is I don't want to use `time.sleep()`.
The reason why is because it makes the players last move not visible.
Anyone has any advice for **other** libraries or codes to do the same thing?

this is the code but I don't blame you if you don't understand.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()

howmanygone = 0
winningcondition1x = False
winningcondition2x = False
winningcondition3x = False
winningcondition4x = False
winningcondition5x = False
winningcondition6x = False
winningcondition7x = False
winningcondition8x = False
winningcondition9x = False
winningcondition1o = False
winningcondition2o = False
winningcondition3o = False
winningcondition4o = False
winningcondition5o = False
winningcondition6o = False
winningcondition7o = False
winningcondition8o = False
winningcondition9o = False
def destroy() :
    time.sleep(5)
    root.quit()
turn = ["x","o","x","o","x","o","x","o","x"]
indexcounter = 0
def one() :
    global winningcondition1x
    global winningcondition1o
    global turn
    global indexcounter
    global howmanygone
    button1.config(text=turn[indexcounter] , state = "disabled")
    howmanygone += 1
    if indexcounter == 0 or indexcounter == 2 or indexcounter == 4 or indexcounter == 6 or indexcounter == 8 :
        winningcondition1x = True
    else :
        winningcondition1o = True
    indexcounter += 1
    winningcondition1x = True
    print(winningcondition1x)
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1x == True and winningcondition5x == True and winningcondition9x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1x == True and winningcondition2x == True and winningcondition3x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1x == True and winningcondition4x == True and winningcondition7x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1o == True and winningcondition5o == True and winningcondition9o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1o == True and winningcondition2o == True and winningcondition3o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1o == True and winningcondition4o == True and winningcondition7o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()

def two() :
    global winningcondition2x
    global winningcondition2o
    global turn
    global indexcounter
    global howmanygone
    button2.config(text=turn[indexcounter], state = "disabled")

    howmanygone += 1
    if indexcounter == 0 or indexcounter == 2 or indexcounter == 4 or indexcounter == 6 or indexcounter == 8 :
        winningcondition2x = True
    else :
        winningcondition2o = True
    indexcounter += 1
    print(winningcondition2x)
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1x == True and winningcondition2x == True and winningcondition3x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition2x == True and winningcondition5x == True and winningcondition8x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1o == True and winningcondition2o == True and winningcondition3o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition2o == True and winningcondition5o == True and winningcondition8o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
def three() :
    global winningcondition3x
    global winningcondition3o
    global turn
    global indexcounter
    global howmanygone
    button3.config(text=turn[indexcounter], state = "disabled")

    howmanygone += 1
    winningcondition3x = True
    if indexcounter == 0 or indexcounter == 2 or indexcounter == 4 or indexcounter == 6 or indexcounter == 8 :
        winningcondition3x = True
    else :
        winningcondition3o = True
    indexcounter += 1
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition3x == True and winningcondition5x == True and winningcondition7x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1x == True and winningcondition2x == True and winningcondition3x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition3x == True and winningcondition6x == True and winningcondition9x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition3o == True and winningcondition5o == True and winningcondition7o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1o == True and winningcondition2o == True and winningcondition3o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition3o == True and winningcondition6o == True and winningcondition9o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
def four() :
    global winningcondition4x
    global winningcondition4o
    global turn
    global indexcounter
    global howmanygone
    button4.config(text=turn[indexcounter], state = "disabled")

    howmanygone += 1
    if indexcounter == 0 or indexcounter == 2 or indexcounter == 4 or indexcounter == 6 or indexcounter == 8 :
        winningcondition4x = True
    else :
        winningcondition4o = True
    indexcounter += 1
    print(winningcondition4x)
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1x == True and winningcondition4x == True and winningcondition7x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition4x == True and winningcondition5x == True and winningcondition6x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1o == True and winningcondition4o == True and winningcondition7o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition4o == True and winningcondition5o == True and winningcondition6o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()

def five() :
    global winningcondition5x
    global winningcondition5o
    global turn
    global indexcounter
    global howmanygone
    button5.config(text=turn[indexcounter], state = "disabled")

    howmanygone += 1
    if indexcounter == 0 or indexcounter == 2 or indexcounter == 4 or indexcounter == 6 or indexcounter == 8 :
        winningcondition5x = True
    else :
        winningcondition5o = True
    indexcounter += 1
    print(winningcondition5x)
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1x == True and winningcondition5x == True and winningcondition9x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    elif howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition3x == True and winningcondition5x == True and winningcondition7x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition2x == True and winningcondition5x == True and winningcondition8x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition4x == True and winningcondition5x == True and winningcondition6x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1o == True and winningcondition5o == True and winningcondition9o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    elif howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition3o == True and winningcondition5o == True and winningcondition7o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition2o == True and winningcondition5o == True and winningcondition8o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition4o == True and winningcondition5o == True and winningcondition6o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
def six() :
    global winningcondition6x
    global winningcondition6o
    global turn
    global indexcounter
    global howmanygone
    button6.config(text=turn[indexcounter], state = "disabled")

    howmanygone += 1
    if indexcounter == 0 or indexcounter == 2 or indexcounter == 4 or indexcounter == 6 or indexcounter == 8 :
        winningcondition6x = True
    else :
        winningcondition6o = True
    indexcounter += 1
    print(winningcondition6x)
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition3x == True and winningcondition6x == True and winningcondition9x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition4x == True and winningcondition5x == True and winningcondition6x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition3o == True and winningcondition6o == True and winningcondition9o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition4o == True and winningcondition5o == True and winningcondition6o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
def seven() :
    global winningcondition7x
    global winningcondition7o
    global turn
    global indexcounter
    global howmanygone
    button7.config(text=turn[indexcounter], state = "disabled")
    indexcounter += 1

    if indexcounter == 0 or indexcounter == 2 or indexcounter == 4 or indexcounter == 6 or indexcounter == 8 :
        winningcondition7x = True
    else :
        winningcondition7o = True
    howmanygone += 1
    print(winningcondition7x)
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition3x == True and winningcondition5x == True and winningcondition7x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1x == True and winningcondition4x == True and winningcondition7x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition7x == True and winningcondition8x == True and winningcondition9x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition3o == True and winningcondition5o == True and winningcondition7o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1o == True and winningcondition4o == True and winningcondition7o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition7o == True and winningcondition8o == True and winningcondition9o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
def eight() :
    global winningcondition8x
    global winningcondition8o
    global turn
    global indexcounter
    global howmanygone
    button8.config(text=turn[indexcounter], state = "disabled")

    howmanygone += 1
    if indexcounter == 0 or indexcounter == 2 or indexcounter == 4 or indexcounter == 6 or indexcounter == 8 :
        winningcondition8x = True
    else :
        winningcondition8o = True
    indexcounter += 1
    print(winningcondition8x)
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition7x == True and winningcondition8x == True and winningcondition9x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition2x == True and winningcondition5x == True and winningcondition8x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition7o == True and winningcondition8o == True and winningcondition9o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition2o == True and winningcondition5o == True and winningcondition8o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()

def nine() :
    global winningcondition9x
    global winningcondition9o
    global turn
    global indexcounter
    global howmanygone
    button9.config(text=turn[indexcounter], state = "disabled")

    howmanygone += 1
    if indexcounter == 0 or indexcounter == 2 or indexcounter == 4 or indexcounter == 6 or indexcounter == 8 :
        winningcondition9x = True
    else :
        winningcondition9o = True
    indexcounter += 1
    print(winningcondition9x)
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1x == True and winningcondition5x == True and winningcondition9x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition7x == True and winningcondition8x == True and winningcondition9x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition3x == True and winningcondition6x == True and winningcondition9x == True :
        print("X Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition1o == True and winningcondition5o == True and winningcondition9o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition7o == True and winningcondition8o == True and winningcondition9o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()
    if howmanygone >= 3 and winningcondition3o == True and winningcondition6o == True and winningcondition9o == True :
        print("O Won")
        destroy()




button1 = Button(root,text=" ",command = one,padx = 15,pady = 10)
button1.grid(row = 0,column = 0)
button2 = Button(root,text=" ",command = two,padx = 15,pady = 10)
button2.grid(row = 0,column = 1)
button3 = Button(root,text=" ",command = three,padx = 15,pady = 10)
button3.grid(row = 0,column = 2)
button4 = Button(root,text=" ",command = four,padx = 15,pady = 10)
button4.grid(row = 1,column = 0)
button5 = Button(root,text=" ",command = five,padx = 15,pady = 10)
button5.grid(row = 1,column = 1)
button6 = Button(root,text=" ",command = six,padx = 15,pady = 10)
button6.grid(row = 1,column = 2)
button7 = Button(root,text=" ",command = seven,padx = 15,pady = 10)
button7.grid(row = 2,column = 0)
button8 = Button(root,text=" ",command = eight,padx = 15,pady = 10)
button8.grid(row = 2,column = 1)
button9 = Button(root,text=" ",command = nine,padx = 15,pady = 10)
button9.grid(row = 2,column = 2)




mainloop()
```

Comment: Please read up on [**lists**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) and [**loops** / control flow](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try `time.sleep()` `pygame.time.wait()` `pyplot.pause()` `.after()` `asyncio.sleep()`

For more detail check 1st answer by 'Trooper Z' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python)