# Python: yahoo_fin.stock_info.get_quote_table() not returning table

Tags: python, web-scraping, yahoo-api, replit

**Goal:**

The goal is to generate a robot in replit which will iteratively scrape yahoo pages like this [amazon page](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN?p=AMZN), and track the dynamic 'Volume' datapoint for abnormally large changes. I'm currently trying to be able to reliably pull this exact datapoint down, and I have been using the [yahoo_fin API](https://github.com/atreadw1492/yahoo_fin) to do so. I have also considered using bs4, but I'm not sure if it is possible to use BS4 to extract dynamic data. (I'd greatly appreciate it if you happen to know the answer to this: can bs4 extract dynamic data?)

**Problem:**

The script seems to work, but it does not stay online due to what appears to be an error in yahoo_fin. Usually within around 5 minutes of turning the bot on, it throws the following error:

```
  File "/home/runner/goofy/scrape.py", line 13, in fetchCurrentVolume
    table = si.get_quote_table(ticker)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yahoo_fin/stock_info.py", line 293, in get_quote_table
    tables = pd.read_html(requests.get(site, headers=headers).text)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 1098, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 926, in _parse
    raise retained
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 906, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 222, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py", line 552, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found
```

However, this usually happens after a number of tables have already been found.

Here is the `fetchCurrentVolume` function:

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si

def fetchCurrentVolume(ticker):

  table = si.get_quote_table(ticker)
  currentVolume = table['Volume']


  return currentVolume
```

and the API documentation is found above under **Goal**. Whenever this error message is displayed, the bot exits a `@tasks.loop` , and the robot goes offline. If you know of a way to fix the current use of yahoo_fin, OR any other way to obtain the dynamic data found in this `xpath: '//div[@id="quote-summary"]/div/table/tbody/tr'`  , then you will have pulled me out of a 3 weeks long debacle with this issue! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to retrieve some data then it cuts out, it is probably due to a rate limit. Try adding a sleep of a few seconds between each one.

[see here for how to use sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python)

Comment: I wondered this as well and should have elaborated. I have used sleep up to 40 seconds, and the error still eventually occurs, and I believe this to be far above the yahoo finance query threshold.

Comment: I saw that you are asking about different ways to get the data including bs4. I used bs4 in the past for this but I now use [yfinance](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) which seems to work pretty well.

Comment: I love yfinance, but volume is one of the only parameters that i could not locate

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the web server bonks out when the tables are being re-written every so often. Or something like that.

If you use a try/except waited a few seconds and then tried again before bailing out to a failure maybe that would work if it is just a hicup once in a while?

```
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si
import time

def fetchCurrentVolume(ticker):
    try:
        table = si.get_quote_table(ticker)
        currentVolume = table['Volume']
    except:
        # hopefully this was just a hicup and it will be back up in 5 seconds
        time.sleep(5)
        table = si.get_quote_table(ticker)
        currentVolume = table['Volume']
    return currentVolume
```

Comment: Great idea, but also did not work! I'm beginning to suspect this issue is on the replit end of things.