# use pygame.time.get_ticks()

Tags: pygame

How do I write and use:

```
pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

Is it a good way to wait some time in an animation but still have code running?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18856389/6220679).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a good way to wait some time in an animation but still have code running? 
The answer is depends on what you are trying to achieve.
Here is an example where time.get_ticks() has a valid use.

http://nullege.com/codes/search/pygame.time.get_ticks

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks.. It doesnt tell me how to use or write the function.

Comment: When answering it is encouraged that you please at least summarize the content from any links in case the links die and someone else would like to use the information in the future