# Why doesn't PyGame draw in the window before the delay or sleep?

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a pong game. When either of the scores hit 10, it is supposed to put up some text on the screen and say the right player has won or left player has won. However, in my program, it isn't working. When it has to show the text that the right or left player has won, it doesn't show it. But it works for everything else. Here is the code:

```
# Importing libraries
import pygame
import random
import time

# Initializing PyGame
pygame.init()

# Setting a window name
pygame.display.set_caption("Ping Pong")

# Creating a font
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)
pong_font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 75)

# Set the height and width of the screen
window_width = 700
window_height = 500
size = [window_width, window_height]
game_win = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
game_win2 = pygame.display.set_mode(size)


# Creating a messaging system
def message(sentence, color, x, y, font_type, display):
    sentence = font_type.render(sentence, True, color)
    display.blit(sentence, [x, y])


# Creating colors
white = (225, 225, 225)
black = (0, 0, 0)
gray = (100, 100, 100)

# Setting up ball
ball_size = 25


class Ball:
    """
    Class to keep track of a ball's location and vector.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0


def make_ball():
    ball = Ball()
    # Starting position of the ball.
    ball.x = 350
    ball.y = 250

    # Speed and direction of rectangle
    ball.change_x = 5
    ball.change_y = 5

    return ball


def main():
    # Scores
    left_score = 0
    right_score = 0

    pygame.init()

    # Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    done = False

    ball_list = []

    ball = make_ball()
    ball_list.append(ball)

    # Right paddle coordinates
    y = 200
    y_change = 0
    x = 50
    # Left paddle coordinates
    y1 = 200
    y1_change = 0
    x1 = 650

    while not done:
        
        # --- Event Processing
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    y_change = -7

                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    y_change = 7

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    y1_change = -7

                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y1_change = 7

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                y_change = 0
                y1_change = 0

        y += y_change
        y1 += y1_change

        # Preventing from letting the paddle go off screen
        if y > window_height - 100:
            y -= 10
        if y < 50:
            y += 10
        if y1 > window_height - 100:
            y1 -= 10
        if y1 < 50:
            y1 += 10

        # Logic
        for ball in ball_list:
            # Move the ball's center
            ball.x += ball.change_x
            ball.y += ball.change_y

            # Bounce the ball if needed
            if ball.y > 500 - ball_size or ball.y < ball_size:
                ball.change_y *= -1
            if ball.x > window_width - ball_size:
                ball.change_x *= -1
                left_score += 1
            if ball.x < ball_size:
                ball.change_x *= -1
                right_score += 1

            ball_rect = pygame.Rect(ball.x - ball_size, ball.y - ball_size, ball_size * 2, ball_size * 2)

            left_paddle_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 25, 75)
            if ball.change_x < 0 and ball_rect.colliderect(left_paddle_rect):
                ball.change_x = abs(ball.change_x)

            right_paddle_rect = pygame.Rect(x1, y1, 25, 75)
            if ball.change_x > 0 and ball_rect.colliderect(right_paddle_rect):
                ball.change_x = -abs(ball.change_x)
                            
            # Here is the where the messaging system doesn't work, I don't know why! It works fine for everything else
            if right_score == 10:
                message("RIGHT PLAYER HAS WON!!", white, 300, 200, font, game_win)
                time.sleep(5)
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif left_score == 10:
                message("LEFT PLAYER HAS WON!!", white, 300, 200, font, game_win)
                time.sleep(5)
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        # Drawing
        # Set the screen background
        game_win.fill(black)

        # Draw the balls
        for ball in ball_list:
            pygame.draw.circle(game_win, white, [ball.x, ball.y], ball_size)

        # Creating Scoreboard
        message("Left player score: " + str(left_score), white, 10, 10, font, game_win)
        message("Right player score: " + str(right_score), white, 490, 10, font, game_win)

        # Drawing a left paddle
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, white, [x, y, 25, 100])
        # Drawing a right paddle
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, white, [x1, y1, 25, 100])

        # Setting FPS
        FPS = pygame.time.Clock()
        FPS.tick(60)

        # Updating so actions take place
        pygame.display.flip()


while True:
    game_win2.fill(black)
    pygame.event.get()
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    message("Pong", white, 280, 100, pong_font, game_win2)
    if 150 + 100 > mouse[0] > 150 and 350 + 50 > mouse[1] > 350:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, gray, [150, 350, 100, 50])
        if click[0] == 1:
            break
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, white, [150, 350, 100, 50])

    if 450 + 100 > mouse[0] > 450 and 350 + 50 > mouse[1] > 350:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, gray, [450, 350, 100, 50])
        if click[0] == 1:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(game_win, white, [450, 350, 100, 50])

    message("Start", black, 175, 367, font, game_win2)
    message("Quit", black, 475, 367, font, game_win2)

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Wrap-up
    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have added a little comment, it is: "`# Here is the where the messaging system doesn't work, I don't know why! It works fine for everything else`". Now when someone scores 10 points, Nothing happens. Its= wait for a couple of seconds. That is so you can read the "Left player has won" or "Right player has won" before the program closes. But it simply doesn't show up! I don't know why! Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The display is updated only if either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
is called. See [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip):

> This will update the contents of the entire display.

Further you've to handles the events with [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump), before the update of the display becomes visible in the window.

See [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

If you want to display a text and delay the game, then you've to update the display and handle the events.

Write a function which delays the game and updates the display. I recommend to use the [`pygame.time`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) module to implement the delay (e.g. [`pygame.time.delay()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html))

```py
def update_and_wait(delay):
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.event.pump()
    pygame.time.delay(delay * 1000) # 1 second == 1000 milliseconds
```

Or even implement a function which its own event loop to keep the application responding. Measure the time by [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks):

```py
def update_and_wait(delay):
    start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print("auit")
                pygame.quit()
                return False
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= start_time + delay * 1000: 
            break
    return True
```

Use the function in the application:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    while not done:
        # [...]

        for ball in ball_list:
            # [...]

            if right_score == 0:
                message_wait("RIGHT PLAYER HAS WON!!", white, 300, 200, font, game_win)
                update_and_wait(5)
                quit()
            elif left_score == 0:
                message_wait("LEFT PLAYER HAS WON!!", white, 300, 200, font, game_win)
                update_and_wait(5)
                quit()
```

Comment: Thanks You have help a lot