# Can someone help me with random "spawning" in Python

Tags: python

I want to do that enemies spawn random but nothing never happens.
My idea was that on some time like 0.1 second there is new random coordinate to spawn enemy but I don't know how to use time.sleep in loop without stopping ALL of the code.

CODE:

```
import random
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
from pygame.locals import*

ran_coordinates_x = random.randint(260, 1160)
ran_coordinates_y = random.randint(260, 730)


def add_enemy(ran_coordinates_x, ran_coordinates_y):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 255), (ran_coordinates_x, ran_coordinates_y), 20)


while running:
    digit = random.randint(1, 100)
    if digit < 50:
        add_enemy(ran_coordinates_x, ran_coordinates_y)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wait some time in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839039/how-to-wait-some-time-in-pygame)

Comment: You are generating your coordinates x and y only once at the beginning of your code, and using the same values again and again

Comment: Yea i know but still nothing is appering.

Comment: If you want a time interval between the spawns, then instead of using time.sleep, get the current time in ms or ns when the game starts.  Then on each pass of the main loop, get the current time and check the difference. If the difference is large enough, then spawn an enemy and update the reference time to what the current time was..

Comment: Can you explain in code please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
pygame.display.update()
```

to show the circle on the screen.

Comment: Yes I have it, this just isnt ALL of the code. Just a part