# How to use time.sleep() in milliseconds

Tags: python, variables, time, sleep

In my code I have a variable called 'time'.

I set it to `2.0` (so I do not get an error when I subtract a float from an int).

I do `time = time - 0.1` (this is so that when this line of code is repeated, it will be shorter by 0.1 seconds each time).

But when I try and put it into `time.sleep` it won't let me (because it's a decimal)

How can I do milliseconds instead so that I can just subtract 100 milliseconds instead?

[Look here for my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hn0U.png)

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is *2.0* supposed to mean? What does *When I call a certain function* mean? What is *time = time - 0.1* supposed to represent? What unit of time are you using? We can't read your mind.

Comment: You should post here actual code and the error it is producing.

Comment: 2.0 is just so that when I subtract 0.1 from time that it won't give me an error for subtracting a float from an int

Comment: And about when I call a certain function was just so that I didn't make it to personal. I have been persecuted for saying stuff like that before, I didn't want to make another mistake.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377454/how-do-i-get-my-python-program-to-sleep-for-50-milliseconds

Comment: Except of overwriting the time module, you are also trying to update it from a function name space without using `global`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call the variable you use `time`, because the module that supplies the `sleep` function is already called `time`. So your variable with the same name will make that module unavailable.

Use a different variable name.

Simple example:

```
import time
x=2.0
while x > 0:
    print(str(x), flush=True)
    time.sleep(x)
    x=x-0.1
```

Comment: No semicolons in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. The documentation also confirms subsecond precision is possible.

> sleep(seconds) 
>   Delay execution for a given number of seconds.  The
>   argument may be a floating point number for subsecond precision. Type:
>   builtin_function_or_method