# For Loop executed every 5 minutes for 24 hours

Tags: python, loops

I have a for loop and I want each iteration to be executed every 5 minutes. Essentially, I want to freeze/sleep the loop for 5 minutes and then continue from where it left 5 minutes ago, NOT to start from the beginning. In total, I want to do this for an entire day (24hours).

Comment: Great! What have you tried so far? What issues are you running into?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get my Python program to sleep for 50 milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377454/how-do-i-get-my-python-program-to-sleep-for-50-milliseconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? The loop runs for (a little more than) twenty-four hours and sleeps for five minutes after each iteration.

```
from time import sleep, time

ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60  # seconds
FIVE_MINUTES = 5 * 60  # seconds


start_time = time()

current_time = start_time
while current_time <= start_time + ONE_DAY - FIVE MINUTES:
    # Do something loopy here...

    time.sleep(FIVE_MINUTES)
    current_time = time()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I adjusted it to my code and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You could define a method that simply calls sleep for 5 minutes and then call that in your loop. Kind of like this

```
import time 

# main loop
for i in .....:
   # do your stuff
   wait5Mins()
   # continue doing stuff

def wait5Mins():
    time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I used the answer I received above first and it works. But thanks for your help anyway!