# How to countdown the code beneath in seconds

Tags: python, time, countdown

I want to make a stopwatch that countdown in real seconds, soo i build a super basic stopwatch but s you expect is this counting down within milliseconds. How can i import real time into this?

```
count = 100

while count > 0:
    print(count)
    count -= 1
```

Comment: Ohh sorry for that, i am a newbie. I am programming in Python

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you need to tell your processor to **wait** (aka sleep) for a second. How this is achieved, depends on the programming language.

**Edit**

For Python, this will help:

```
import time
while True:
    print("This prints once a minute.")
    time.sleep(60) # Delay for 1 minute (60 seconds).
```

where fractions of a second as in `sleep(0.05)` are valid as well.

(taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377454/how-do-i-get-my-python-program-to-sleep-for-50-milliseconds))

Comment: ahhh, than its  time.sleep()

Comment: If the anwer helps, you might press the check mark to 'accept' the answer to state that the question is considered answered.