# How to delay in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops

a = [1,2,3]
for i in a:
print (i)

here is a simple code I would like to delay the print result while the for loop goes through the list. meaning I want a delay between the value 1 and 2 in the list item

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get my Python program to sleep for 50 milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377454/how-do-i-get-my-python-program-to-sleep-for-50-milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sleep` function inside the `time` module:

```py
from time import sleep

a = [1, 2, 3]
for i in a:
    print(i)
    sleep(0.5). # Sleeps for 0.5 seconds
```

Comment: There is a dot after the sleep, not a big impact for code reading but it sure raises exception.