# My game in pygame is not working properly

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make tic tac toe with pygame. If you click in any one of the squares, an x will be displayed. The problem is that it takes a lot of clicks to display the x. here's the code:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        event = pygame.event.wait()
        screen.fill(bg_color)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 250 < mouse_pos[0] < 300 and 250 > mouse_pos[1] > 199:
            mouse_clicked1 = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 301 < mouse_pos[0] < 351 and 249 > mouse_pos[1] > 201:
            mouse_clicked2 = True
    if mouse_clicked1:
        screen.blit(x, object_top_left)
    if mouse_clicked2:
        screen.blit(x, object_top)
```

Comment: Are you perhaps starving the event handler of resources by running in a tight loop?

Comment: I didn't understand what you said

Comment: Your code is running in a tight loop. It is possible that that means that the Python runtime and/or the Pygame code that is responsible for collecting mouse clicks from the operating system often have no time to run. You can confirm or rule out this theory by adding a delay to the end of your `while True` loop. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377454/how-do-i-get-my-python-program-to-sleep-for-50-milliseconds). If that causes the behavior you describe to go away, then resource starvation of the event handler was indeed the culprit.

Comment: How much of a delay should I give

Comment: It's not important for the sake of the experiment. 10 ms, 100 ms, whatever.

Comment: It's better than before, but it still takes a few clicks. How can I fix that?

Comment: And you're sure that it not just the case now that you click and then have to wait for the delay you added to pass? If that's not it, I can't help you any further.

Comment: Please post your full (runnable) game code. I don't think the code above is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.event.wait()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.wait) waits for a single event from the queue. Remove the function a use the events which you get from [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
If the event type is `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` (or `MOUSEBUTTONUP`), then the mouse position is stored in the `pos` attribute of the [`pygame.event.Event()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object:

```py
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 250 < event.pos[0] < 300 and 250 > event.pos[1] > 199:
            mouse_clicked1 = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and 301 < event.pos[0] < 351 and 249 > event.pos[1] > 201:
            mouse_clicked2 = True
    
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    if mouse_clicked1:
        screen.blit(x, object_top_left)
    if mouse_clicked2:
        screen.blit(x, object_top)
```

Note, [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) get and removes all the events from the queue. Hence the call to `pygame.event.wait()` in the loop, will rarely return any event.

---

Furthermore, I recommend to use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects and [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint):

```py
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            rect1 = pygameRect(250, 200, 50, 50)
            if rect1.collidepoint(event.pos):
                mouse_clicked1 = True
            rect2 = pygameRect(300, 200, 50, 50)
            if rect2.collidepoint(event.pos):
                mouse_clicked2 = True
    
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    if mouse_clicked1:
        screen.blit(x, object_top_left)
    if mouse_clicked2:
        screen.blit(x, object_top)
```