# How to time this loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Hello I just make this script loop, but now it loops indefinitely, I would like to make the loop every 5 seconds for example, I run the script and wait 5 seconds and run again.
This is the code that i have right now.

```
import gdown

def test():
    url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1RUySVmR2ASrnNf3XV4sdIpKD4QbUlQL8A'
    output = 'spam.txt'
    gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)

while True:
    test()
```

Comment: what about time.sleep(*time*)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get my Python program to sleep for 50 milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377454/how-do-i-get-my-python-program-to-sleep-for-50-milliseconds)

Comment: @Miguel the answer you have accepted is quite inefficient, consider accepting any one of the other answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import time

def test():
    print("running code")

start = time.time()

while 1:
    if time.time()-start >= 5:
        test()
        start = time.time()
```

The 5 is for the seconds. This way means that the rest of your program does not have to wait for five seconds, which maybe more useful.

Comment: Note that if you do this method you will use a bunch of cpu power just spinning through the loop doing nothing.  The other solutions that use `time.sleep` keep the CPU usage to a minimum.

Comment: Only use this method if you want only that chunck of code to run every second and the rest of the program to carry on as normal

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way is to simply add a pause.

```py
import gdown
from time import sleep

def test():
    url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1RUySVmR2ASrnNf3XV4sdIpKD4QbUlQL8A'
    output = 'spam.txt'
    gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)

while True:
    test()
    sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just `sleep` for 5 seconds then:

```
import time

while True:
    test()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: oh jajajaja xD ok thanks