# I want to control the execution interval of Python code in detail. (I used time.sleep)

Tags: python, sleep

There is a certain While infinite loop statement, but given the Time.sleep(0.001) condition, it only executes 700 times per second. I want to run 5,000 to 50,000 times per second, but the argument of time.sleep() can't be lower than 0.001?

```
import time

i = int()
while True:
    time.sleep(0.001)
    #~
    #Code Block(It's private because it's code I'm reluctant to reveal.)
    #~
    print("%d"&i) #700 print() calls per second.
```

Comment: I don't think Python runs fast enough to even print that many numbers in a second without sleep

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, it is. So I want to put the argument of sleep() smaller than 0.001. But it doesn't seem to be able to apply a factor lower than 0.001 in Python.

Comment: What happens if you take out the "sleep"?

Comment: If you want the code to run faster, blocking the thread is clearly not the answer, regardless of how low the value can be

Comment: On ideone - `timeit.timeit(lambda: "-".join(map(str, range(1000))), number=10000))` - takes longer than 1 second, so 5000 or 50000 will definitely take longer

Comment: Warning that time.sleep may sleep longer than the requested interval. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=sleep#time.sleep

Comment: Try Unix time? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62719717/15350738

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep(0.001)` sleeps for 1 ms or 1/1000 sec.
Therefore you cannot get more than 1000 loops per second.

> but the argument of time.sleep() can't be lower than 0.001

This is not true. The argument to time.sleep() is a float:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep